# Ошибка установки pip install в PyCharm

Tags: python, django, ssl, pycharm

При попытке установить Django в терминале PyCharm появляется ошибка:

*pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Py thon is not available.*

Изменения в path и openSSL не помогли, какие еще есть способы?

*ос - windows 10

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: Alpensin, windows 10

Comment: А питон устанавливался инсталятором с python.org или может анаконда или вроде того?

Comment: Alpensin, параллельно стоит анаконда

Comment: Ну вот используемый интерпретатор установлен через анаконду?  Возможно советы отсюда по Windows10  будут полезны https://stackoverflow.com/q/45954528/7753445